# Unique representation of a vector(the proof of the converse)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

[image]

I know that if $B$ is a basis for $\mathbf V$,  there exist unique scalars $\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n$ with the desired property
 I wonder if the reverse proposition(vice versa proposition) is also true.

Can you show the proof that the reverse proposition(vice versa proposition) is also true?

Comment: Use $0=0.a_1+0a_2+\cdots+0a_n$ where an arbitrary $v$ can be written uniquely as $v=a_1u_1+\cdots+a_nu_n$

Answer (score 1):

If there exists unique scalars for each $v$ such that $v=\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n$, then the only scalars for $v=0$ are $\alpha _1=\cdots =\alpha_n=0$.  Thus the $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy and follows almost from the definition of basis. Suppose that $B=\lbrace x_1,\ldots,x_n\rbrace$ is the basis, and that a vector $x$ is written as $$x=\alpha_1x_1+\ldots +\alpha_n x_n=\beta_1 x_1 +\ldots \beta_n x_n$$this implies $$(\alpha_1-\beta_1)x_1 +\ldots +(\alpha_n - \beta_n)x_n=\overrightarrow{0}$$
However since $\lbrace x_1,\ldots,x_n\rbrace$ is a basis all its vectors are linearly independent, so $\alpha_i-\beta_i=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you show the proof that the reverse proposition(vice versa proposition is also true)?